# A question about linear transformation and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space over the reals, $n \ge 1$. Let $L(V)$ denote the vector space of all linear transformation $T:V \to V$, and let $A(V)$ be the set $A(V)=\{\,T \in L(V)\ |\ {\rm dim}(T(V)) \lt n\ \}$. Find all $n$ such that $A(V)$ is a subspace of $L(V)$.

This question I have no idea at all. Hope somebody could help me. Thanks

Comment: if you identify $T$ with a square matrix, then rank $n-1$ or less matrices are going to give you that $T(V)$ is a $V$'s proper subspace.   Right??

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

(1) $\;T\notin A(V)\iff T\;$ is invertible

(2) If $\;n>1\;$ then for *any* $\;T\in A(V)\;$ you can always find some $\;S\in A(V)\;$ s.t. $\;T+S\;$ is invertible...(thinking in matrix terms may be helpful)

Comment: why should one want this $S$??

Comment: Closedness, @janmarqz ...?

Comment: Ah!.. ok.. then $A(V)$ can't be subspace. Right?

Comment: Indeed so, @janmarqz..at least when $\;n>1\;$ ...

Comment: In fact, the proof I have doesn't use matrices at all but simply operators, so perhaps my last remark above may be a little misleading.

Comment: Any time, @user121819 ...